# Relative Minimum via Derivative using R

Tags: r, minimum, derivative

I am trying to get the value of x that would minimize my equation y. I would like to use R.

The equation is:

`y= [(a-bx)^2] / {[2bx /(1+x)]+c}`
 where a, b, c are all constant, but different to one another.

Thanks.

Comment: Isnnthis homework?  Fine if so but please add the homework tag.  Look at optim() for numerical minimization.

Answer (score 4):

The standard optimize function should be sufficient for simple one-dimensional minimization:

```
a <- 2
b <- 1
c <-1
func <- function(x){(a-b*x)^2/((2*b*x/(1+x))+c)}

optimize(f=func, interval = c(-3,3))
```

`$minimum
[1] -0.3333377`

`$objective
[1] -277201.4`